# How to remove disk from RAID1 without knowing the /dev/XXX name?

Tags: raid, sles

BEFORE:

```
SERVER:~ # mdadm --detail /dev/md5
/dev/md5:
    Version : 00.90.00
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 18 14:53:33 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 67103360 (63.99 GiB 68.71 GB)
    Device Size : 67103360 (63.99 GiB 68.71 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
Preferred Minor : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon May 27 21:32:01 2013
      State : clean, no-errors
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0


    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8      129        0      active sync   /dev/sdi1
       1       0        0       -1      removed
       UUID : 5cd4bFe4:dd1b759f:b7e070fe:c44bfRef
     Events : 0.36000940
```

ADDING A DISK TO RAID1:

```
SERVER:~ # mdadm --add /dev/md5 /dev/sdj1
mdadm: hot added /dev/sdj1
```

AFTER:

```
SERVER:~ # mdadm --detail /dev/md5
/dev/md5:
    Version : 00.90.00
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 18 14:53:33 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 67103360 (63.99 GiB 68.71 GB)
    Device Size : 67103360 (63.99 GiB 68.71 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon May 27 21:32:32 2013
      State : clean, no-errors
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1


    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8      129        0      active sync   /dev/sdi1
       1       0        0       -1      removed
       2       8      145       -1      spare   /dev/sdj1
       UUID : 5cd4bFe4:dd1b759f:b7e070fe:c44bfRef
     Events : 0.36000955
SERVER:~ #
```

QUESTION: how can I remove this line/disk from md5?

```
       1       0        0       -1      removed
```

Probably this is the reason why /dev/sdj1 is marked as spare...

I already tried to remove it:

```
SERVER:~ # mdadm /dev/md5 -r detached
mdadm: cannot find detached: No such file or directory
SERVER:~ #
```

OS: SUSE LINUX Enterprise Server 9.4

UPDATE: so can I remove a disk from an md* device using it's number? ( in this case the number would be "1" )

Comment: `mdadm --examine /dev/sd[ij]1`?

Comment: The array might be rebuilding, you have to verify that first.

Answer (score 1):

That is (more or less) the expected behaviour. Quoting the man page:

> --add: hot-add listed devices.  If a device appears to have recently been part of the array (possibly it failed or was removed) the device is  re-added  as described  in the next point. If that fails or the device was never part of the array, the device is added as a hot-spare. If the array is degraded, it will immediately start to rebuild data onto that spare.

Thus: The disk is not recognized as a former member of the array. Asking a suboptimal question you said nothing about that.

> Probably this is the reason why /dev/sdj1 is marked as spare.

It's the other way round: Because `sdj1` is still marked as spare the "removed" line is still there. I don't know though why the spare disk is not automatically used for filling the empty slot (as the man page claims). Maybe it changes its state from "spare" to "active" if the sync is finished. Have a look at `/proc/mdstat`.